# Swift 3.0 : task block is not executed

Tags: swift, xcode8

I am new to Swift and have a question. I have the following block for code to run a task. However, this task block is not executed when i run from Xcode 8.2.1. What am i doing wrong?

```
// Execute HTTP Request
let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request as URLRequest) {
 (data, response, error) in

 // Check for error
 if error != nil
 {
 print("error=\(error)")
 return
 }
 // Print out response string
 let responseString = NSString(data: data!, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue)
 print("responseString = \(responseString)")


 // Convert server json response to NSDictionary
 do {
 if let convertedJsonIntoDict = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: []) as? NSDictionary {

 // Print out dictionary
 print(convertedJsonIntoDict)

 // Get value by key
 let sessionId = convertedJsonIntoDict["sessionId"] as? String
 print(sessionId!)

 }
 } catch let error as NSError {
 print(error.localizedDescription)
 }

 }
 task.resume()
```

Is a completionHandler required? i am running this inside a main.swift file.

Comment: Seems possible your program is ending before the task finishes. Provide more context for the code.

Comment: As an aside, and completely unrelated to your question, your code will be simplified if you excise the `NSString`, `NSURLRequest`, and `NSError` references. Use `String`, `URLRequest` and `Error`, instead. Then no casting is needed and the `encoding` is simpler.

Comment: @Rob thats right, i am not seeing any of the print error or response String in the console after run.

Comment: @MikeTaverne This is a simple console project. i am just experimenting with how the task() handler is used in swift and running this from main.swift

Comment: Sorry, my bad. i realized my program was ending before task was completed. thanks for the tip @Mi

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your program is ending before the task finishes.

I ran it and got this output:

```
Hello, World!
Program ended with exit code: 0
```

I then added this after `task.resume()` just to keep the program from stopping:

```
while true {    
}
```

And I could see it attempted to access the URL I provided.